# Help needed with minimum cost flow problem

Tags: optimization, operations-research, network-flow

I am trying to solve a very simple minimum cost flow problem using optimization software. However, the software keeps on complaining about the problem being infeasible, which means I have most certainly not expressed the model/constraints correctly. The network is illustrated below:

[image]

- Supply nodes: 0 and 1 (75 units for each node)
- Demand nodes: 4 (50 units),5 (60 units), 6 (40 units)
- Costs in red along the arcs
- Node 3 has a max capacity of 50 units

I tried to solve the problem by defining the following equations:

Minimize the objective function:
$5 x_{02}+8x_{03}+7x_{12}+4x_{13}+x_{24}+5x_{25}+8x_{26}+3x_{34}+4x_{35}+4x_{36}$

I have also defined the following constraints:

- $x_{02}+x_{03} = 75$
- $x_{12}+x_{13} = 75$
- $x_{24}+x_{34} = 50$
- $x_{25}+x_{35} = 60$
- $x_{26}+x_{36} = 40$

At the transshipment nodes 2 and 3:

- $x_{02}+x_{12}-x_{24}-x_{25}-x_{26} = 0$ (at node 2)
- $x_{03}+x_{13}-x_{34}-x_{35}-x_{36} = 0$ (at node 3)

Maximum capacity constraints at node 3:

- $x_{03} \leq 50$
- $x_{13} \leq 50$
- $x_{34} \leq 50$
- $x_{35} \leq 50$
- $x_{36} \leq 50$

Am I missing any other constraints? Are any of the above constraints expressed in a wrong way?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the second constraint should be $x_{12}+x_{13}=75$? And is the max capacity at node 3 supposed to be in aggregate or for each individual branch? That is, should each input into node 3 and each output be capped at 50, or should the sum of inputs and sum of outputs be capped at 50?

Comment: @AmaanM Thanks for pointing this out. This was actually a typo when I was typing in my question.Checked the code which uses the right indices. Still getting an infeasible result

Answer (score 1):

Node capacity of 50 means the sum of incoming flows (which is equal to the sum of outgoing flows) at that node is at most 50.  This is a tighter constraint than the five $\le$ constraints that you specified.

An optimal solution, with objective value 1250, is
\begin{matrix}
i &j &x_{i,j} \\
\hline
0 &2 &75 \\
0 &3 &0 \\
1 &2 &25 \\
1 &3 &50 \\
2 &4 &50 \\
2 &5 &50 \\
2 &6 &0 \\
3 &4 &0 \\
3 &5 &10 \\
3 &6 &40 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: That was a typo while typing my question. Unfortunately I am still getting an infeasible solution

Comment: @BigONotation Set lower bound = upper bound = Rob's solution for each variable, rerun your model (presumable still infeasible), then ask the solver for an irreducible infeasible subset (IIS) of constraints. One or more of those constraints is buggered.